# PHP upgrade to v.5.3 breaks includes?

Tags: php

I was asked to fix a site that was fine just days ago and now is not able to include files due to the host's upgrade of the PHP to v.5.3

For each include I now get two Warnings, like this:

> Warning: include_once(file.php) [function.include-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/content/anotherFile.inc.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'file.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in
>   /home/content/anotherFile.inc.php on line 2

I don't really want to rewrite the site. Is there a way to fix the path? It is on a shared hosting and I am not able to modify php.ini

I searched quickly and it appears an issue with PHP 5.3, which goes away with 5.3.1... Bug?

What are the possible solutions?

---

UPDATE: I think the issue is with the code. It was written years ago and $_GET values were used as $value. Changing to $_GET['value'] seem to have fixed a few issues.

Comment: Possible solutions are: (a) move to a PHP 5.2 host, though this isn't optimal, or (b) copy it to your local machine, test against 5.3, fix and re-upload. I suspect in this case it is just a broken include path - trace the paths in the real error message, and correct them as necessary.

Comment: Is the difference that the files were actually being included before, and now they're not, or just that the warnings weren't showing up before? What's the web server / OS? Is PHP installed as a web server module or as CGI?

Comment: (If you need further help on this problem, let us see the code where the `include_once` statement is - paste the _relevant bit_ into your question).

Comment: The includes were there before. It may of may not be includes issue... a class that used to connect to db started complaining, so I thought of upgrading to a newer version, which does have additional includes. On my dedicated server works fine, but on this complains...

Comment: Most shared host environments have a means of tweaking the php.ini on a per customer basis. I'd try to find it in their docs, support or forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem is caused by a [deprecated php.ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php): `register_globals = on`.

That would cause your `$GET` variables to get extracted and be globally available like you described in your edit.

In php 5.3 this setting is deprecated but not yet removed, so while you are refactoring, you can turn it back on again so that your site is working again. **However**, note that you do need to get rid of this setting as it is a security risk and it has been completely removed in php 5.4